SqlAlchemy query limit
Please tell me how to limit the output of the number of rows in sqlalchemy?
I have 2 tables, they are linked through many to many:
class Track(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'track'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title: Mapped[str]
    created_at: Mapped[datetime.date] = mapped_column(default=func.now())
  
    base_collections: Mapped[List['BaseCollection']] = relationship(
      secondary=track_base_collection_association, back_populates='tracks'
    )

class BaseCollection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'base_collection'
  
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
  
    tracks: Mapped[List['Track']] = relationship(
      secondary=track_base_collection_association, back_populates='base_collections'
    )


track_base_collection_association = Table(
    'track_base_collection_association',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('track_id', ForeignKey('track.id')),
    Column('base_collection_id', ForeignKey('base_collection.id'))
)

How do I make a request base_collection.id == 1, tracks I received no more than 50 pcs?
The limit can be set to receive the base_collection, but I cannot imagine how the limit can be divided into tracks like this:
select(BaseCollection).where(BaseCollection.id == collection_id).options(joinedload(BaseCollection.base), selectinload(BaseCollection.tracks).limit(limit))

